# How to get 2 fields in one goup with regex?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I work on an application which read txt files with regular expressions. The txt files are different so the app has a database with a mapping table in which I store the regular expressions.

In a file there are these 2 rows:

> Script Start Date: Fri 11/10/2017
>   Script Start Time: 23:26:20.61

I need a "start datetime" in one group (Fri 11/10/2017 23:26:20.61). How can I collect these in one group with just regex? Can I exclude the "Script Start Time:" string between the 2 fields or maybe can I collect the 2 fields in groups then concatenate them into one group somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(@"path to txt file");
  Match match = Regex.Match(fileContent, @"Script Start Date: (.+)\nScript Start Time: (.+)");
  if (match.Success)
  {
    // Here I use Substring method, to cut out "Fri", as it's not necessary to parse to DateTime
    DateTime.TryParse(match.Groups[1].Value.Substring(4) + " " + match.Groups[2], out DateTime dt);
    Console.WriteLine(dt);
    Console.ReadKey();
  }
```

Explanation of a pattern: `Script Start Date: (.+)\nScript Start Time: (.+)`:

first it looks for words `Script Start Date:`, then it captures into first group everything until the end of a line (date part), then it matches newline character (`\n`), then again, matches `Script Start Time:` literally and then captures rest of a line into second capturing group (time part).

Then I check if match was successfull, if it was, use captruing groups to construct `DateTime` variable.

EDIT:

Use this pattern `Script Start Date: \w+ (.+)\nScript Start Time: (.+)`, so you can concatenate two groups and directly have datetime in well-known format (I added `\w+` to match `Fri`, day generally, and capture only proper date part).
Then use first and second capturing group directly to have a date.

Comment: Thank you but my app iterate through the mapping table and just called the regular expressions. Can I do this with just a regular expression without any plus C# code?

Comment: @Atesz Why don't you want any C# code? You need to use at least one line, so why not few more to make it safe??

Comment: Because it is an universal app and it is just one type of txt files, other has normal datetime field and the core code work with others so first I try to create a regular expression which can collect this 2 fields in one group and if i can't then i will modify my code but i prefer to create a good regex for this.

Comment: @Atesz This is the good regex, the one you are asking for is impossible to achieve. I doubt that you can capture two separate texts into one group. You didn't give any reason why you would need to do it with one line of code (this is horrible idea, as it reduces scalability, maintainability and readability of code).

Comment: The only reason is that it is my job to try to create a regex for that which we can store in the database (and read from that when we iterate through the regexps) and don't modify the project. Not my idea :D

Comment: @Atesz Then you have one regex, I don't know where are you having problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a substring approach it is easier to debug, but make sure your lengths never change

```
    var inputTxt = "Script Start Date: Fri 11/10/2017 \n Script Start Time: 23:26:20.61";
    var firstCondition = "Start Date: ";
    var dateIndex = inputTxt.IndexOf(firstCondition) + firstCondition.Length;

    var secondCondition = "Start Time: ";
    var timeIndex = inputTxt.IndexOf(secondCondition) + secondCondition.Length;
    //gets format count (no need to change)
    var dl = "Fri 11/10/2017";
    var tl = "23:26:20.61";
    //result
    var date = inputTxt.Substring(dateIndex, dl.Length) + " " + inputTxt.Substring(timeIndex, tl.Length);
```